# How do I make the camera follow a animated character while focusing on the face?

Tags: camera

I've tried parenting the camera to my character, armature, an empty then parenting the empty to the character, and the camera still won't follow the character. How can I get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean by "follow"?  Do you want the camera to stay stationary but always pointed at the character or do you want the camera to move when the character moves?  Different solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Select the Camera, shift select the armature, switch to pose mode, select an appropriate moving bone (Maybe Hip bone), press Ctrl P > Bone.
This makes the camera move solidly with that bone.

Then you can add to the camera a Dumped track constraint, targeting the armature > head bone, so that the camera always looks at the head.

To add some more control you can bone parent an empty to the head bone in the same way and make the damped track constraint target the empty, so that you can adjust the aim animating the empty.